# Datastage.. I have a field which has the value say 59.0900..I want to convert it to 05909

Tags: datastage, infosphere-spl

I have a field which has the value say 59.0900..I want to convert it to 05909
Can somebody help me with that..Im working on datastage IBM infosphere

Answer (score -1):

- Convert the field into String
- Trim the trailing zeros and decimal point
- convert back to Decimal or integer